# Calling a function on a servlet from a JSP page

Tags: java, function, jsp, servlets

I think my question title explains it all. It's for an assignment for school I have to do, I have to program some sort of bulletinboard. I figured out the useBean part more or less, and that it is used to call set properties. Only what if I want to call another function on the servlet which isn't a setter? How does that work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only functions you can call from JSP to a Servlet are `doGet()` or `doPost()` as a result of a http request.

You can submit the the request from the JSP as follows:

```
response.sendRedirect("servleturl")
```

Or you can use a html `<form>`:

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post">
```

I would favor the second option if possible and try to avoid java code in your JSPs.

Comment: I'd say that you can call whatever method you've defined. You can call it within the scriptlet `<%` and you can define them from JSP using declarations `<%!`.